# Is this complete partial order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Is $(\mathbb{N} , \#)$ complete partial order, where $m\#n$ iff $(\exists k \in \mathbb{N})m=kn$.
I proved it's partial order.
For completeness I take directed subset and I know there is upper bond $1$ but does it mean there is supremum?

Comment: What do you mean by complete? Dedekind complete, every bounded subset has a supremum?

Comment: Surely the supremum of a set is its gcd?

Comment: complete- every directed subset has supremum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that if $m\#n$ then $n\leq m$. Conclude that if $D$ is a directed subset then above every $m\in D$ there are only finitely many points; and recall that a finite partial order always have a maximal element.

Comment: If I read the OP right, it has, $1$. The definition is $m \# n \iff n \mid m$, and if I interpret it right, the divisor is considered greater than (or equal to) the multiple.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seemed weird that the relation was defined "backwards" for that. I'll fix my hint.

Comment: Thank you =) I had hunch how to prove it but simply couldn't get it

Comment: @Mare: You're welcome.